# How to add extra columns to a select statement that contain percentages of a previous column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm able to produce a table like this using a select statement:

```
column1 total
-------------
Item A  360
Item B  440
Item C  180
```

This is the SQL statement I use to create the above table:

```
select column1, sum( order_total) as total
from report
group by column1;
```

How can I modify my SQL stement to add a 3rd and 4th column in it which is a % of the total column is displayed? The percentage value is based on what value is in column1. So that in the end I'm trying to create a table that looks like this:

```
column1 total  percentage_a percentage_b
----------------------------------------
Item A  360    108          252
Item B  440    220          220
Item C  180    70           110
```

So in the table above the percentage_a and percentage_b columns are a certain percentage of the total column. How can I modify my SQL code so that Item A row will have a 30/70 split and Item B column will be a 50/50 split.

Thanks for any help. I'm a novice.

Comment: I see no relationships between the numbers in your desired results and the explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, for the poor description. 

So Item A is a 30/70 percentage split. Item B is 50/50 and so on. So the percentage_a and percentage_b columns need to be a certain percentage of the total column.

Comment: You need to provider more details, Is the % to calcualted based on some value you forgot to mention it the Question?

Comment: So you have 30/70 and 50/50 in other table or these are hard coded values?

Comment: Yes, these would have to be hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select 
    column1, 
    sum(order_total) as total,
    sum(order_total) * 0.7 as percent_70_30,
    sum(order_total) * 0.5 as percent_50_50
from 
    report
group by 
    column1;
```

Comment: But the percentage breakdown differs for each row. So ItemA, ItemB and ItemC have different percentage breakdowns.

Comment: What is it you want to use for the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: Each row or item would have a different percentage that would have to be hardcoded. Item A is 30%, B is 50% and C is 39%.

Comment: Item A is 30% of what?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the poor phrasing of the question once again. This is what I was looking for:

```
select report.instituiton_name, sum( report.order_total ) 
as instituton_totals, t1.betteru_percentage, t2.cp_percentage
from bi_all_sales_report report
left join (
    select instituiton_name, ( 
    CASE  
        WHEN instituiton_name = 'abc' THEN sum( order_total ) * 0.30 
        ELSE sum( order_total ) * 0.50
    END ) as betteru_percentage
    from bi_all_sales_report
    group by instituiton_name
) t1 on t1.instituiton_name = report.instituiton_name
left join (
    select instituiton_name, ( 
    CASE  
        WHEN instituiton_name = 'abc' THEN sum( order_total ) * 0.70 
        ELSE sum( order_total ) * 0.50
    END ) as cp_percentage
    from bi_all_sales_report
    group by instituiton_name
) t2 on t2.instituiton_name = report.instituiton_name

group by instituiton_name
```